# ESRI Linear Referencing and negative lengths

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, linear-referencing, dynamic-segmentation

I have been asked this question regarding Linear Referencing (for Arcmap 10.1), but i do not have much experience with it so I am hoping someone out there can help.

Essentially, I want to know how events are handled if a route changes length (ie. point a to point b length is changed, and point a is now in the middle of the line length).

Hope that makes sense!?

Answer (score 3):

A good starting point to learn about such recalibration of routes is the **[Calibrate Routes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000004000000)** tool documentation.

Comment: Hello, thank you.  After some reading then posing the question to ESRI, they advised if there are negative values in the events table, these values are skipped when using the ‘Make Route Event’ tool.  It will also skip any values that are greater than the length of the line.

In the case of editing routes and them changing length, the ‘Transform Route Events’ tool is used.  It takes the old route, new route and table of distance as inputs, then creates a new table updating the distance based on the differences between the two routes.